# Reading line by line in String Array

Tags: c, arrays, avr

I have an array which is stored in my program memory

```
const char* const paragraph[] PROGMEM = {
    "First Line",
    "Second Line"
};
```

How do I read one string at a time so that it output

```
First Line
Second Line
```

Comment: I guess you can ignore `PROGMEM` as it tells the AVR to place the array in program memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(paragraph)/sizeof(paragraph[0]); ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", paragraph[i]);
}
```